# Identify old comic about man who discovers he is an android

Tags: story-identification, comics

I bought this first issue during the late 80's or early 90's. My vague recollection of the first issue's plot is that  there's this long haired dude; blonde if I'm not mistaken. I think he was a rock musician, but I'm not sure. He certainly looked like the archetypal hair metal musician.

Most of the action in this first issue consists of a flying ball-like robot chasing him and shooting at him and he doesn't know why. I remember distinctly that the protagonist calls it "Ball!" at some point, and I'm pretty sure part of the action happens at an empty or mostly empty parking lot that is several stories high.

At some point he falls from the building and that's when he finds out he's actually a robot or android himself as some contraption in his body prevents full impact with the floor (I think it was something coming out of his chest to absorb the impact).

Eventually he defeats the robot and it appears that the series is set up to have him investigate the twin mysteries of his identity and why someone is trying to snuff him.

I can't remember who published it or anything beyond the 1st chapter. Someone suggested to me it might be Marvel's Longshot, but while the look is there, the story doesn't match my recollection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone found the answer for me somewhere else. The name of the comic is [CyberRad](http://www.comicvine.com/cyberrad-1/4000-33722/). The first issue's cover immediately jogged my memory.

> A frightened, confused teenager flees for his life when pursued by a pair of powerful and deadly robots. With no memory of his own identity, he has no idea why they’ve chosen him as their target. But what is most surprising is the fact that he’s not only surviving their assault, he’s actually able to fight back. The resulting battle only raises more questions: Why are they so intent on killing him and who’s responsible for their lethal programming? Is he some kind of robot or cyborg himself? His attackers seem to know all the answers, which only makes his situation worse. If the youth doesn’t fight back, he’ll definitely die. But if he succeeds in defeating his attackers, he may never learn the answers he so desperately needs.